# overlap off by 1px in Firefox and IE but not in Chrome

Tags: css

In Chrome the ul li ul border is exact over de border of the menu ul, but in Internet Explorer and Firefox it's off by 1px.

http://jsfiddle.net/5qasu929/

```
#menu ul li ul {
display:none;
position:absolute;
z-index:999;
height:auto;
margin-top:16px;
margin-left:-0px;
background-color:#EFEFEF;
border-bottom:1px solid #C7C7C7;
border-left:1px solid #C7C7C7;
border-right:1px solid #C7C7C7;
}
#menu ul li {
display:table-cell;
height:50px;
vertical-align:middle;
border-bottom:1px solid #C7C7C7;
margin-left:0;
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of changes should make this more uniform across browsers:

- Add `position:relative;` to `#menu ul li` to make the child `ul` position relative to it
- Add `top:50px;` to `#menu ul li ul`. This is the same as the `height` of the parent `li`
- Remove `margin-top:16px;` from `#menu ul li ul`

```css
#menu {
  width: 950px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}
#menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
}
#menu ul li {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 50px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #C7C7C7;
  margin-left: 0;
  position: relative; /*Add*/
}
#menu ul li a {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #024fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  padding: 5px;
}
#menu ul li:hover {
  background-color: #E3E3E3;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #024fff;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
  -moz-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
  -o-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
  -ms-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
  transition: background-color 200ms linear;
}
#menu ul li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  height: auto;
  /*margin-top:16px;Remove*/
  margin-left: -0px;
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #C7C7C7;
  border-left: 1px solid #C7C7C7;
  border-right: 1px solid #C7C7C7;
  top: 50px;/*Add*/
}
#menu ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
  border-top: 1px solid #024fff;
}
#menu ul li ul li {
  min-width: 80px;
  display: block;
  height: 23px;
  padding: 9px 35px 0px 5px;
  border: 0px;
}
#menu ul li ul li:hover {
  border-bottom: 0px;
}
#menu ul li ul li:before {
  content: '- \00a0 ';
  color: #024fff;
}
#menu ul li ul li a {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sub1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub1</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Home2</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sub1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub1</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Home3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Home4</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sub1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub1</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed. Only had to change the top:50 to 49px because it should overlap.

Answer (score 0):

Use [border-box](/questions/tagged/border-box) property of css,

> Specify that `<li>` elements should have padding and border included in
>   the element's total width and height:

```
#menu ul li {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    margin-top:-1px;
}
```

Comment: Still the same problem unfortunately. The only different is that the li goes up a pixel in Chrome.

Comment: @user2586633 now add margin-top:-1px; to **li** or **ul**

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `A` tag height within a parent `LI` in order to position your sub menu

First, add a `display:block` `and height:100%`  to your `A`:

```
#menu ul li a {
    font-size:18px;
    color:#024fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    padding:5px;
    display:block;
    height:100%;
}
```

---

Delete Li's height (Height will depend on the font-size & padding of your `A` tag

```
#menu ul li {
    display:table-cell;
    height:auto;
    vertical-align:middle;
    border-bottom:1px solid #C7C7C7;
    margin-left:0;
}
```

---

And finally remove `margin-top` toi submenu :

```
#menu ul li ul {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:999;
    height:auto;
    /*margin-top:16px;*/
    margin-left:-0px;
    background-color:#EFEFEF;
    border-bottom:1px solid #C7C7C7;
    border-left:1px solid #C7C7C7;
    border-right:1px solid #C7C7C7;
}
```

---

Prevent `submenu > a` from being `display:block`:

```
#menu ul li ul li a {
    font-size:16px;
    padding:3px;
    display:inline;
}
```

> [Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/53z84xfL/)